# How to add DataGridTemplateColumn (Button column) as the last column in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'am working with c# and WPF, i have a DataGrid control to which i display data from a DataTable dynamically and also AutoGeneratedColumns property of DataGrid control is set to false.

Now the problem is that i want to add another column (**DataGridTemplateColumn**) in the DataGrid control which will be the last column.

I have used code like below to add Button column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn >
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                      <Button Click="btnDetails">Details</Button>
                </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

By using above code, button column is added to DataGrid but as a FIRST column and then all columns of DataTable is added after that dynamically.

So i just want to add this DataGridTemplateColumn in the last of all columns.
Please Help me out with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please share full xaml code of DataGrid.Columns

Comment: '<DataGrid.Columns>                                                                                     
       <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                                  <Button Click="btnDetails">Details</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>'

Comment: Do you add other columns programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You may use DisplayIndex property for the column but I recommend you to set AutogenerateColumns to false in the DataGrid declaration , and then add columns manually in the desired order:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Property1}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Property2}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Click="btnDetails">Details</Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>            
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, But if i set AutogenerateColumns to false then how can i load DataTable to DataGrid control dynamically?i am Using MySql query to get table and then i set ItemSource property of DataGrid Control to DataTable.

Comment: You can keep it like that, just replace Property1, Property2,...,  etc with the columns names from you table.

Comment: Hey,but i am creating columns dynamically then how can i declare columns name before in the place of Property1 and so on.?

Comment: How are you creating the DataTable? Where your data come from? Update the Q with the code if necessary.

Comment: i am querying MySql DB and get DataTable as a response. After that i set ItemSource property of DataGrid control to DataTable.

Comment: By default the columns in datatable are given the same name as the output columns from your query. That are the names that you use to define your datagrid columns.

Comment: Yes the columns returned as output will be the columns of DataGrid control, but i want to add extra column which is not in DataTable and also as the last column of the DataGrid control,this is the problem.

Comment: That is why you have to use AutoGenerateColumns="False" and then state the columns explicitly, included the button column, see the snippet from my answer.